# converting variable created in real time to string

Tags: java, variables

Sorry, I don't know the correct wording for this. I've tried searching everywhere.

I want to convert a value created in real time to a fixed value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

//make new button
            JButton btnGroup = new JButton(listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(0, listOfFiles[i].getName().length() - 4));
            btnGroup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfFiles[i].getName()))) {
```

EDIT: clearer explanation.

If I make a button like this in real time with an on click action: "filereader(listOfFiles[i].getname()", [i] will produce the error "Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"

Instead of:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(listOfFiles[i].getName()))
```

it should say:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))
```

But I won't know the name of the file beforehand.

Comment: Do you want only the name of the file without the extension ?

Comment: Try `listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(0, listOfFiles[i].getName().lastIndexOf('.')`

Comment: the file name without extension works fine, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make the contents of Filereader() final, before adding the action to the button.

fixed code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

      final String filetoread = listOfFiles[i].getName();

        JButton btnGroup = new JButton(listOfFiles[i].getName().substring(0, listOfFiles[i].getName().length() - 4));
        btnGroup.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filetoread))) {
```